# Dimensions --- counter-intuitive?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, documentation

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the meaning of `Dimensions` in Mathematica, but the following two examples seem very counter-intuitive to me.

If we define

```
a = {1,2,3} 
b = {4,5,6}
```

then we compute the dimension of its dot product `Dimension[ a . b ]`, I get the "empty" result

```
{}
```

But if I consider instead,

```
aa = {a1, a2, a3}
bb = {b1, b2, b3}
```

and compute the same thing `Dimension[ aa . bb ]`, I get the result

```
{3}
```

Is this behavior to be expected? I understand that the first case has known constants, and while the second case has unknown constants. But regardless, both are simply scalars, and I would expect `Dimensions` would return the same answer in both cases.

Comment: `Dimensions` does not only work with lists. Take a look at `FullForm` of expressions you use in `Dimensions`.

Comment: @Kuba I see. Once I look at the `FullForm`, I see that the first and second case yield wildly different forms. But is there a function in Mathematica where if I literally want to just "count dimensions", they would both yield the same result? For instance, as far as I can tell, in Mathematica, an $n \times m$ matrix of known constants and unknown constants yield the same answer in `Dimensions`.

Comment: So you would like `Dimensions` which only respects `List` head? Good question.

Comment: You might consider doing a preliminary test with `ArrayQ[]`.

Comment: Perhaps `TensorDimensions` would be better used in this context.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> So you would like `Dimensions` which only respects `List` head? Good question. -- [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/141777/dimensions-counter-intuitive#comment383161_141777)

From the documentation:

> The "array" is considered full only when it has the same head as at the top:
>
> ```
> Dimensions[f[g[x, y], g[a, b], g[s, t]]]
> {3}
> ```

So I believe, this could be achieved like so:

```
listDimensions[arg_] := Rest@Dimensions[{arg}]
listDimensions[a.b]
listDimensions[aa.bb]
```

> ```
> {}
> {}
> ```

Comment: Missed this for some reason. I have given you my last upvote for today.