# ArrayDepth and Dimensions count square brackets as a dimension

Tags: list-manipulation

> `ArrayDepth[expr]` gives the depth to which `expr` is a full array, with all the parts at a particular level being lists of the same length, or is a `SparseArray` object.

OK, so `ArrayDepth` of a symbol (i.e. a scalar quantity) gives 0:

```
In[1]:=  ArrayDepth[f]
Out[1]:= 0
```

But:

```
In[2]:=  ArrayDepth[f[x]]
Out[2]:= 1
```

Why? `f[x]` is still not a List!

When I have a `List` of vector components, then it makes no difference if these components are functions or just symbols:

```
In[3]:= ArrayDepth[{f, g, h}]
Out[3]:= 1

In[4]:= ArrayDepth[{f[x], g[x], h[x]}]
Out[4]:= 1
```

Is there a function in *Mathematica* that returns the true "nestedness" of the `List`, i.e. the number of indices needed to access elements of the `List`, without paying attention to square brackets? (I assume regular nested lists, where all levels have the same length). So it should give 0 for any non-`List`, 1 for vectors, 2 for regular matrices, etc.

Comment: You missed the "Generalizations and Extensions" part of the docs for `ArrayDepth[]`, I take it. Anyway... "I assume regular nested lists, where all levels have the same length" - so, something that passes `ArrayQ[]`.

Comment: Very related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/141777/26956

Comment: @J.M. *so something that passes `ArrayQ`* Unclear, if you ask me. So a "regular" matrix which has some of its elements as lists has an `ArrayDepth` of 0?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP, I was hoping the OP would look at the first point of the docs for `ArrayQ[]`: "`ArrayQ[expr]` gives `True` if `expr` is a full array or a `SparseArray` object, and gives `False` otherwise."

Comment: I think an answer using the option AllowedHeads (currently undocumented, but probably not going away) would be useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something relatively simple:

```
myArrayDepth[arr_] := If[ArrayQ[arr], ArrayDepth[arr], 0]
```

Test:

```
ArrayDepth[f[f[a, b], f[c, d]]]
   2

myArrayDepth[f[f[a, b], f[c, d]]]
   0
```

---

Alternatively, use `TensorRank[]`:

```
TensorRank[{{1, 3}, {2, 4}}]
   2

TensorRank[SparseArray[{1, 1} -> 1, {2, 2}]]
   2
```

which remains unevaluated if given something that isn't a `List[]` or a `SparseArray[]`:

```
TensorRank[f[f[a, b], f[c, d]]]
   TensorRank[f[f[a, b], f[c, d]]]
```

and throws a warning if not passed a rectangular array:

```
TensorRank[{{1, 2}, {3}}]
>> TensorRank::rect: Nonrectangular array encountered.
   1
```

Comment: Yeah, I've implemented code like that, but I was actually wondering about the logic behind the built-in ArrayDepth. What is the reason for it to consider square brackets as indicator of dimension if no curly braces are given?

Comment: @ThatGuy The reason is that curly braces are shorthand for `List[]`. `List[List[1, 2], List[3, 4]]` is the same as `{{1,2},{3,4}}` and has an array depth of 2. If we replace `List` with `f` to get `f[f[1,2],f[3,4]]` the depth won't change.

Comment: @ThatGuy square brackets are irrelevant, that's just the way syntax is done in Mathematica. What's relevant is what is immediately before the square brackets, in this case `List` or `f` and all instances of that must be the same for it to be a full array (so `f[f[1,2]]` is fine (depth 2), but `f[g[1,2]]` isn't (depth 1).

Comment: `TensorRank` is a nice choice. At least its output is always independent of whether I use square brackets inside.

Answer (score 7):

There is an undocumented option `AllowedHeads` that can be used for this purpose (so the usual warnings about undocumented features applies here):

```
ArrayDepth[f[f[a,b], f[c,d]], AllowedHeads->{List}]
ArrayDepth[f[f[a,b], f[c,d]], AllowedHeads->{f}]
```

> 0
>
> 2

You can use [`SetOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetOptions) in an `init.m` file to change the default:

```
SetOptions[ArrayDepth, AllowedHeads->{List}];
ArrayDepth[{{a,b}, {c,d}}]
ArrayDepth[f[f[a,b], f[c,d]]]
```

> 2
>
> 0

Note that you can also mix and match heads using this option, but note that the heads have to be the same at any particular level:

```
ArrayDepth[f[{a,b}, {c,d}], AllowedHeads->{List, f}]
ArrayDepth[f[{a,b}, f[c,d]], AllowedHeads->{List, f}]
```

> 2
>
> 1

Answer (score 2):

In line with my answer from the linked question:

```
myArrayDepth[arr_] := ArrayDepth[{arr}] - 1
```

Just like J.M.'s answer:

```
ArrayDepth[f[f[a, b], f[c, d]]]
myArrayDepth[f[f[a, b], f[c, d]]]
```

> ```
> 2
> 0
> ```