# How to get the correct dimension of a scalar expression?

Tags: list-manipulation

`Dimensions` works pretty well with an array.

```
Dimensions[a]
Dimensions[{a}]
Dimensions[{{a}}]
Dimensions[{a, b}]
```

> {}
>
> {1}
>
> {1, 1}
>
> {2}

When I do

```
Dimensions[a b]
```

> {2}

However,

```
Dimensions[{a b}]
```

> {1}

What is wrong here and how can I get the correct dimension of `a b`?

`ArrayDepth` also shows similar behaviour

```
ArrayDepth[a]
ArrayDepth[a b]
ArrayDepth[{a b}]
```

> 0
>
> 1
>
> 1

Comment: [A related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159957) I would suggest using `TensorRank[]` first, and then if it doesn't evaluate, you can return `{}` as the dimensions.

Comment: This is how I am cheating now. As `Dimensions[{a}]` = `Dimensions[{a b}]` = 1. So the answer is `Dimensions[{x}]-1`.  I was just wondering how Mathematica sees `a b` or `a+b`. But it does not work for `{a,b}` Let me put that on edit.

Comment: You could just use `SetOptions[Dimensions, AllowedHeads->List]` as described in my answer to the linked question.

Comment: @CarlWoll, it works `Dimensions[a, AllowedHeads -> {List}]` gives `{}`. I like the `ArrayDepth` more. Could you post it as an answer? I have not accepted anything whole day

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A very similar [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/159957/45431) was asked concerning [`ArrayDepth`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayDepth), and my answer to that question was to use the option `AllowedHeads`:

```
Dimensions[f[a b], AllowedHeads->{List}]
Dimensions[{f[a b]}, AllowedHeads->{List}]
```

> {}
>
> {1}

One can also use [`SetOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetOptions) to change the default:

```
SetOptions[Dimensions, AllowedHeads->{List}];
Dimensions[f[a b]]
Dimensions[{f[a b]}]
```

> {}
>
> {1}

Note that while the option `AllowedHeads` is not documented, the name may change in the future, but the functionality will not go away.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way out based on @J.M. suggestion

```
dim[s__] := Module[{d},
             d = Dimensions[{s}];
             If[Length[d] == 1, d[[1]] - 1, d[[2;;-1]]]]

dim[a]
dim[a b]
dim[{a}]
dim[{a, b}]
dim[{{a},{b}}]
```

> 0
>
> 0
>
> {1}
>
> {2}
>
> {2,1}